# How to read this array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have read other questions regarding reading arrays in PHP and implemented the suggested solutions but these do not seem to work for me...
My array looks like this:-

```
 { 
    [0]=> array(6) 
    {   ["name"]=> string(9) "Test04Feb" [0]=> string(9) "Test04Feb" 
        ["paymentvalue"]=> string(6) "500.00" [1]=> string(6) "500.00" 
        ["transactiondate"]=> string(19) "2020-02-05 13:29:37" [2]=> string(19) "2020-02-05 13:29:37" 
    }

    [1]=> array(6) 
    {   ["name"]=> string(9) "Test04Feb" [0]=> string(9) "Test04Feb" 
        ["paymentvalue"]=> string(7) "1500.00" [1]=> string(7) "1500.00" 
        ["transactiondate"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01 05:30:00" [2]=> string(19) "1970-01-01 05:30:00" 
    } 

    [2]=> array(6) 
    {   ["name"]=> string(9) "Test04Feb" [0]=> string(9) "Test04Feb" 
        ["paymentvalue"]=> string(5) "90.00" [1]=> string(5) "90.00" 
        ["transactiondate"]=> string(19) "2020-02-05 18:12:18" [2]=> string(19) "2020-02-05 18:12:18" 
    } 
}
```

And none of these work for me:-

```
  $stmt1->execute([$myname]);
  $value = $stmt1->fetchAll();
 ...
    foreach ($stmt1 as $row1) { 
         echo $row1[0]->name;
         echo $row1['0']['transactiondate'];
         echo $row1[0]['paymentvalue'];
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `$row1` is an array as indicated in your dump. In `foreach` should use `$value` and not `$stmt`. Then:

```
foreach ($value as $row1) { 
    echo $row1['name'];
}
```

P.S. If you want to get only associative keys, use like this:

```
$value = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
foreach ($stmt1 as $row1) {
```

`$row1` is each individual record from the database.  Therefore, rather than having to use `[0]` as in your code, you should simply be using...

```
echo $row1->name;
```

etc.

To check this for yourself, use something like `print_r($row1);` in the loop to see what each loop has to work with.

Comment: thanks so much for your help but this does not work for me... for your ref. `print_r($row1);` gives me  `Test04FebArray ( [name] => Test04Feb [0] => Test04Feb [paymentvalue] => 500.00 [1] => 500.00 [transactiondate] => 2020-02-05 13:29:37 [2] => 2020-02-05 13:29:37 )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using foreach

```
foreach ($stmt1 as $row1) { 
         echo $row1['name'];    
    }
```

or you can use

```
echo $stmt1[0]['name'];
```

Hope this helps you